# Is it possible to enable and subscribe to Ubuntu Advantage from a disconnected server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-advantage

I would like to use Ubuntu Advantage to obtain FIPS compliant modules, however, my server is in a closed-loop environment. Is it possible to activate a UA subscription and migrate packages without a direct internet connection?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a product that Canonical sells, and that we do not provide customer support for here. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-enable-fips-on-ubuntu-in-air-gapped-environments/26583/1, which addresses Canonical products for this specific situation.

Comment: Ubuntu Advantage is a Canonical service, according to the Help Center, Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical are on-topic on Ask Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic This question is not off-topic and should be left open. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19922/is-extended-security-maintenance-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment44661_19922